# Blurring a .BMP with box BLUR in C

Tags: c, pointers, blur

To resume. the code I ve written below doesn t get me a blur image. But a black IMAGE instead ( except for the pixel edges).
For testing i ve just tried the interior PIXELS, without edges RGBTRIPLE pixels because I wanted to see if I was making well so far.

Could anybody tell me whats wrong with my code, please?
is muy BUFFER RGB newImage correct done?? if image[height][width].rgbtRed it means that newImage[height][width].rgbtRed will exist?? thanks in advance

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{


    //create a buffer to allocate new pixels.
    RGBTRIPLE newImage[height][width];

    // iterate through each row
    for (int i = 0 ; i < height ; i++)
    {
         // iterate through each column passing through every RGBTRIPLE
        for ( int j = 0; j < width ; j++)
        {
            int redSum = 0;
            int greenSum = 0;
            int blueSum = 0;

             //counter for pixels being add in every avg.
             //int count = 0;
             // take the average amount of RGB of every pixel in a range of 3x3 pixels
             // avg for left top corner
             /*if ( r == 0 && l == 0) {

             }
             // avg left bottom corner
             else if ( r == height - 1 && l == 0 ){

             }
             // avg right top corner
             else if ( r == 0 && l == width - 1){

             }
             // avg left bottom corner
             else if ( r == height - 1 && l == width - 1){

             }
             // avg  top side
             else if ( r == 0 && l > 0 && l != width - 1) {

             }
             // avg right side
             else if ( l == width - 1 && r > 0 && r != height - 1) {

             }
             // avg bottom side
             else if ( r == height - 1 && l > 0 && l != width - 1) {

             }
             // avg left side
             else if ( l == 0 && r > 0 && r != height - 1){

             }*/

             for ( int iy = -1 ; iy >= 1 ; iy++)
             {
                 for ( int jx = -1 ; jx >= 1 ; jx++)
                 {
                     redSum = redSum + image[i + iy][j + jx].rgbtRed;
                     greenSum = greenSum + image[i + iy][j + jx].rgbtGreen;
                     blueSum = blueSum + image[i + iy][j + jx].rgbtBlue;
                     //count++;
                     }
             }

             int avgRed = redSum / 9;
             int avgGreen = greenSum / 9;
             int avgBlue = blueSum / 9;
             newImage[i][j].rgbtRed = avgRed;
             newImage[i][j].rgbtGreen = avgGreen;
             newImage[i][j].rgbtBlue = avgBlue;

        }

    }

    for ( int y = 1 ; y < height - 1; y++)
    {
        for ( int x = 1; x < width - 1; x++)
        {
            image[y][x].rgbtRed = newImage[y][x].rgbtRed;
            image[y][x].rgbtGreen = newImage[y][x].rgbtGreen;
            image[y][x].rgbtBlue = newImage[y][x].rgbtBlue;
        }

    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: This: `for ( int py = 0 ; py >= 2 ; py++)` looks wrong. If you correct the comparison, you'll access the pixel buffer out of bounds, because contrary to what you've said you don't consider only the inner pixels, at least not with the large block of tests commented out.

Comment: Please, please never use the variable name l. Was that `l` or was it `1`? In a monotype font you can tell by squinting, but not in proportional font. It just makes code very hard to read. Anyway, using `r` and `l` together deceives the reader into thinking they are `right` and `left` but they are `row` and `column`.

Comment: `/*if ( r == 0 && l == 0) {
 }
 // avg left bottom corner
  else if ( r == height - 1 && l == 0 ){
...  else if ( l == 0 && r > 0 && r != height - 1){
 }*/` does nothing.  Why is it there?

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks. I ll take that in consideration.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it was my next move... but I was trying to fix  the first issue.

Comment: @MOehm I can see. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

A major mistake not already mentioned in a comment is that `redSum`, `greenSum` and `blueSum` are initialized to 0 only once, while they must be set to zero before each pixel is processed, so better move the definitions right before the `for ( int py = 0 ; py >= 2 ; py++)` loop.

Comment: Also, the second pair of loops which copies the new image to the old, have their limit off by one. I think I can see why - the edge pixels have been skipped, but then the loops' initial `0` is incorrect. When the code is completed, don't divide by `9` but by the number of pixels that could be averaged at the edges (which you also can sum).

Comment: Thanks @WeatherVane I corrected all these u said. Now I have the 4 edges without edition. But the no edges pixels are BLACK.

I recon is there is something wrong with the buffer..
`//create a buffer to allocate new pixels.
    RGBTRIPLE newImage[height][width];`
 and then...
`newImage[i][j].rgbtRed = avgRed;
   newImage[i][j].rgbtGreen = avgGreen;
   newImage[i][j].rgbtBlue = avgBlue;`

.rgbtRed .rgbtGreen . rgbtBlue really exist for newImage 2 array??

Comment: You could add the corrected edition to your question, so that we can see whether there's still a cause of undefined behavior.

Comment: Good, only you'd better not changed the original code, rather added the modified version.

Answer (score 0):

It's hardly believable how the many eyes (including mine) who looked at the code could overlook the main, simple error - the inner loops (in their original as well as in the edited version) are never executed:

```
             for ( int iy = -1 ; iy >= 1 ; iy++)
             {
                 for ( int jx = -1 ; jx >= 1 ; jx++)
```

Of course, the `iy >= 1` condition is false from the start; you surely meant `iy <= 1` and `jx <= 1`.

Comment: issue Resolved! it was that loop exactly :)